# Neo4J returned many values

Tags: neo4j

I have query like this:

```
MATCH p = (ob:Obiect)<--(w:Word { value:'human' })-[*]-(x) RETURN {id: id(x), value: x.value}
```

I am returning "x" but i want to return also the “w”. The big question is: how to have “w” returned?

I tried like this:

```
MATCH p = (ob:Obiect)<--(w:Word { value:'human' })-[*]-(x) RETURN {id: id(x), value: x.value, rootid: id(w)}
```

but then the output looks like

```
x.id | x.value | w.id | w.value
x.id | x.value | w.id | w.value
x.id | x.value | w.id | w.value
```

but for NULL values of x there are no values of “w”, but I also need them.

Answer (score 1):

try `OPTIONAL MATCH`, see: http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.5/query-optional-match.html

```
MATCH (ob:Obiect)<--(w:Word { value:'human' })
OPTIONAL MATCH (w)-[*]-(x) 
RETURN {id: id(x), value: x.value, rootid: id(w)}
```